# How to add column with the kafka message timestamp in kafka sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect

I am configuring my connector using properties/json files, I am trying to add a  timestamp column containing the kafka timestamp when it read the message from source connector without any success.

I have tried to add `transforms`, but it's always null and my sink connector "big query" it return me an error

> Failed to update table schema

I did put these configurations in bigquery connector properties

```
transforms=InsertField
transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field=fieldtime
transforms.InsertField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
```

My source Config Sap connector

```
{
    "name": "sap",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "com.sap.kafka.connect.source.hana.HANASourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "10",
        "topics": "mytopic",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:sap://IP:30015/",
        "connection.user": "user",
        "connection.password": "pass",
        "group.id":"589f5ff5-1c43-46f4-bdd3-66884d61m185",
        "mytopic.table.name":                          "\"schema\".\"mytable\""  
       }
}
```

My sink Connector BigQuery

```
name=bigconnect
connector.class=com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector
tasks.max=1

sanitizeTopics=true

autoCreateTables=true
autoUpdateSchemas=true

schemaRetriever=com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever
schemaRegistryLocation=http://localhost:8081

bufferSize=100000
maxWriteSize=10000
tableWriteWait=1000

project=kafka-test-217517
topics=mytopic
datasets=.*=sap_dataset
keyfile=/opt/bgaccess.json
transforms=InsertField
transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field=fieldtime    
transforms.InsertField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
```

Comment: which sink connector are you using`?

Comment: bigquery i have tried with transforms.InsertSource.timestamp.field but it give an error regardign schema can't be modified

Comment: can you share your full Kafka Connect config (worker and connector), as well as the log from the Kafka Connect worker?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt the sources are different multiple database, the destination connector is Bigquery I updated my answer with my config

Comment: That's not what I asked :) can you share the full contents of your Kafka Connect configuration files (worker and connector), as well as the log from the Kafka Connect worker?

Comment: That error looks very specific to BigQuery... Did you *already have* data there? If so, it seems it's not letting you add a new field for the timestamp

Comment: It would still be nice if you could edit your question to include the full config like Robin asked

Comment: Hi I did as asked, i did put the configurations i am using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**OLD ANSWER** 
I think i reached to understand the problem behind

First of all you can't use the transform InsertField in any Source Connector because the Timestamp value for the msg is assigned at writing time into the topic so it's not something the connector can already know,
for JDBC connector there is this ticket 
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/311

and in sap source connector is not working  as well.

Second BigQuery connector has a bug that doesn't allow the usage of InsertField to add the timestamp to every table as mentioned here

https://github.com/wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery/issues/125#issuecomment-439102994

So if you want use bigquery as your output the only solution right now is to manually edit the schema of each table to add the column before loading the cink connector

**UPDATE 2018-12-03**
The final solution to always add the message timestamp in SINK connector. Let's assume you want add the timestamp to EVERY table of sink connector

in your **SOURCE CONNECTOR** put this configuration

```
"transforms":"InsertField"
"transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field":"fieldtime", 
"transforms.InsertField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value"
```

This will add a column name called "fieldtime" to every source tables

in your **SINK CONNECTOR** put those configuration

```
"transforms":"InsertField,DropField",
"transforms.DropField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value",
"transforms.DropField.blacklist":"fieldtime",
"transforms.InsertSource.timestamp.field":"kafka_timestamp",
"transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field":"fieldtime",
"transforms.InsertField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value"
```

this will virtually remove the column fieldtime and add it again with the timestamp of the message

This solution will automatically add the column with the right value without any addition operation

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your error is coming from BigQuery, not Kafka Connect.

For example, start a Connect Console Consumer in standalone mode, you would see messages like

`Struct{...,fieldtime=Fri Nov 16 07:38:19 UTC 2018}`

---

Tested with `connect-standalone ./connect-standalone.properties ./connect-console-sink.properties`

I have an input topic with Avro data... Update your own settings accordingly

**connect-standalone.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081
key.converter.schemas.enable=true

value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://schema-registry:8081
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

plugin.path=/usr/share/java
```

**connect-console-sink.properties**

```
name=local-console-sink
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=input-topic

transforms=InsertField
transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field=fieldtime
transforms.InsertField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
```

Comment: In my caseThe problem is present in Source Connector and Sink connector. about BigQuery-Sink actually the problem  was related with the Connector that don't manage well the transforms.InsertField.timestamp. And about source connector, if you use transforms.InsertField.timestamp  this will be always NULL. All topics have ROWTIME column but i can't use it

Comment: KSQL has a "ROWTIME column" ... the actual message probably does not because there's no such thing as columns in a Kafka message... That being said, it's `record.timestamp()` of the Java API, which is the field gotten by `timestamp.field=fieldtime`... And all connectors support all the same transforms, it's not specific to a certain one. In any case, Confluent has a blog including using BigQuery https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-wrangling-apache-kafka-ksql